# Trigger BackgroundTask either any of two conditions: PushNotification Received or using Geofence

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, microsoft-metro

I have as single `BackGroundTask`. Can we start this `BackgroundTask` using both `PushNotification` or using "Geofencing" technique in a same app?
My requirement is that, `BackgroundTask` should start in either any of the following two cases:

1. When push notification is received, which I already implemented on my app and it is working well.
2. When user change its location, using "Geofencing" technique which I need to implement on my app.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You can add as many background tasks as per your requirement in `package.appmanifest`. I have added two `BackgroundTasks` and works perfectly. I completed my task successfully. 
[image]